# Scroll block HTML

Tags: html, css, scroll

I started doing the mobile version of design
and when I try to scroll fast on phone, the scrolling stops and I should wait a bit.

In project I use fulpage js library but that's now the problem, there should be something with overflow property I think.

```
html, body{
   font-family: sans-serif;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   // height: 100%;
   height: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden !important;
   
}
```

[Here](https://kushimarket.com) is the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; on the container element and scroll-snap-align: start; on the child element should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks much for help!:)